# set the background transparent on android nativescript?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

[image: I want to achieve this kinda transparency on my view as displayed by alert view]

I want to achieve this kinda transparency on my custom view as displayed by alert view for Android application.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Dlucidone I had this solved by using custom overlay from css.

```
<GridLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        // All your page content goes here! 
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="dimmer" visibility="{{showLoading ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'}}"/>
    <GridLayout rows="*" visibility="{{showLoading ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'}}">
        <ActivityIndicator busy="true" />
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Set the dimmer class to background transparent css, with width and height to 100%

Information how to use visible and collapsed
https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/06/05/nativescript-showing-and-hiding-elements/

BTW there is a problem with android on setting isUserInteractionEnabled 
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3215

Comment: thanks for the response!. what I want is a shadow over the base view and custom view over it. The base layer should be visible as you can see in the picture above same kinda implementation.

Comment: @dlucidne
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-dialog
Plugin! hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to show an activity indicator as an overlay with a dimmed background, you could use this one: https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator

```
import {LoadingIndicator} from '@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator'
const loader = new LoadingIndicator()
loader.show({dimBackground: true})
loader.hide()
```